# Can the /t/ and /v/ sounds be dropped in "what," "that" and "of"?

Tags: pronunciation, phonetics, consonants, fast-speech-rules

Is it ok to drop the 't' sound in these example:

- wha that (what that)
- tha the (that the)

& the 'v' (like in the the word 'of') sound

- matter o fact (mater of fact)

of course, to a native english speaker

Comment: In what contexts would you expect to say *what that* and *that the*? Are you trying to emulate some dialect?

Comment: @StoneyB- He asked me *what that* animal was doing, and I told him *that the* chipmunks around here frequently forage for seeds.  Just off the top of my head.

Comment: Define "*OK*". OK to whom, in what context? Primarily opinion-based.

Answer (score 2):

Summary answer: Sort of but not really.

Details: In articulate speech, the ends of 'what', 'that', and 'of' are never dropped, and are pronounced distinctly. In BrE (standard or RP), the word final 't' is released (or aspirated) so is very clear. In AmE, word final 't' is unaspirated and so doesn't sound as clear. In fast or inarticulate speech, BrE tends towards converting to a glottal stop (like in Cockney) or a dental flap in AmE, but may not be heard in either at all. So even though you may hear nothing, the native speaker is making an attempt at a sound, and the native hearer will hear a large accent difference between barely perceptible attempt and not attempting to pronounce it at all.

As to 'of', the analysis is similar, but it is very common to recognize hard to perceive 'of', resulting in spelling that reflects this: "land o lakes", "child o mine". This is not pronounced 'owe' but like 'uh' (a schwa).

Second Summary:
Do not intentionally try to say 'tha the' = /ðæ ðə/. You should try to say /ðæt ðə/ and end up with /ðæʔ ðə/ or /ðæ dðə/. The flap may get lost but it'll change everything around it enough to be distinct from not saying it.

Comment: Definitely not /ðæɹ ðə/, that would be a dialectal pronunciation of ‘there the’. Before another consonant, /t/ is not normally flapped at all, so you'd expect /ðædðə/ (essentially with a voiced dental affricate).

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet edited for your comment

Answer (score 0):

No.

If you are trying to emulate a specific dialect, learn to speak unaccented English first (whether AmE or RP), then layer the specific changes characteristic of that accent on top of the correct foundation.

When native speakers drop consonants, it's from laziness, not because they believe it is a correct alternate. If you have to ask them to repeat themselves, most will enunciate more carefully, and the consonants will reappear.

Comment: Are you saying there is such a thing as "unaccented" English? That is like saying a black car is colorless because you are mostly used to seeing black cars. Every native speaker of a particular dialect speaks that dialect fluently, and if that means "dropping" a consonant sound, it's a dialectal feature, not laziness.

Comment: Sometimes it's a result of fast speech, which does not require letter-by-letter enunciation, but that is part of spoken language, not a deficiency. Usually a person sounds off when they "enunciate more carefully," because it's not the way speech works.